# Arrange containers based on weight in different levels of PalletRack in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have an agent *Container* and it has a parameter: *weight*. The parameter *weight* draws its values from a custom distribution(mentioned below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRx86.png)). Now, I want to arrange the containers based on its weight in the pallet racks. The heavier ones should go to the bottom levels of pallet rack and lighter ones should be at the top. The properties of my palletRack is also mentioned below [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBK04.png). What should I write in ***Pallet Rack/Rack System*** field of ***rackStore*** block in order to achieve this? Or if there is some other way to do this please let me know.

As of now, I am arranging the containers on the basis of other two parameters: *carrier* & *type*. I want to add this additional criteria of weight. I have mentioned my current rackStore properties here. [rackStore-properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdszt.png)
This is the current code in ***Pallet Rack/Rack System*** field :

(agent.carrier==Truck && agent.type==C20 ? palletRack4 : (agent.carrier==Truck && agent.type==C40 ? palletRack6 :(agent.carrier==Train && agent.type==C20 ? palletRack5 :palletRack7)))

Thank you in advance for your help!

[weightDistribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRx86.png)
[palletRack-properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBK04.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am placing the container in a particular cell of the palletRack(i.e. with a given value for row, position & level).The row and position is defined as parameters of the agent Container. The level depends on the weight parameter of Container which is defined using a function. The values of row, position & level mentioned in rackStore properties can be found here: [rackStore properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkUvY.png).

Here, agent.row= uniform_discr(0,1) as we have only two rows for a 2 rack 1 aisle palletRack. agent.position= uniform_discr(0,9) as the palletRack has 10 cells.

The function getLevel can be found here: [function body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh9sd.png)

This approach assigns containers in a particular weight range to a particular level in the palletRack, but I would like it to be more generic such that, if the incoming container can be stored on any level, provided the containers below it are heavier.

Comment: Yes, it is one approach that I could think of. Although its not a perfect one.